# How to connect private area using Python and requets

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I try to login to the member area of the following website :
https://trader.degiro.nl/

Unfortunately, I tried many way without success.
The post form since to be a json it's the reason why I sent a json instead of the post data

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
data = {"username":"test", "password":"test", "isRedirectToMobile": "false", "loginButtonUniversal": ""}
url = "https://trader.degiro.nl/login/#/login"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.62 Safari/537.36'}
r = session.post(url, headers=headers, json={'json_payload': data})
```

Does any one have a idea why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Could you expand on *"doesn't work"*? What response do you get? Is it really expecting the username and password in the post body, rather than e.g. `Authorization` headers?

Comment: When I make a request using that login page, it goes to `https://trader.degiro.nl/login/secure/login`, not `#/login`. Also I don't see a `json_payload` parameter in the request body, just the `data`.

Comment: I have a 200 respond from the server but when I try to access to a private page I have an error.
@jonrsharpe changing the url is maybe the solution !
At least now I have a PHPSESSID in my cookies (I haven't it before)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the request my browser sends, the code should be:

```
url = "https://trader.degiro.nl/login/secure/login"
...
r = session.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

That is, there's no need to wrap the data in `json_payload` and the url is slightly different to the one for viewing the login page.

Comment: ok, I believe it works with this url because I get the PHPSESSID.
But I can't get the JSESSIONID which is in my cookie when I log in by Firefox